# Assimp library error: taking address of packed member

Tags: c++, pointers, assimp

I wanna implement `assimp` library in my `NDK` project with android studio, everything works fine but once i tried to use materials I got the following error:

```
assimp/types.h:208:19: error: taking address of packed member 'r' of class or structure 'aiColor3D' may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Werror,-Waddress-of-packed-member]
    return *(&r + i);
```

this is `CMakeLists` flags

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Werror")
```

Comment: Which version is currently in use?

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed on the latest version. You can get the current master from [github](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/archive/master.zip)